# Show that there cannot exist two distinct positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that both $a^m+b^m=c^m$ and $a^n+b^n=c^n$ hold.

Tags: calculus

> Consider three positive real numbers $a,b$ and $c$. Show that there cannot exist two distinct positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that both $a^m+b^m=c^m$ and $a^n+b^n=c^n$ hold.

---

**My Solution:**
Given, $a^m+b^m=c^m$
$\implies\ 1+(\frac{b}{a})^m=(\frac{c}{a})^m$
$\implies\ 1=(\frac{c}{a})^m-(\frac{b}{a})^m$

Again, we can rewrite
$a^n+b^n=c^n$
$\implies\ 1+(\frac{b}{a})^n=(\frac{c}{a})^n$
$\implies\ 1=(\frac{c}{a})^n-(\frac{b}{a})^n$

Now, comparing we get
$(\frac{c}{a})^m-(\frac{b}{a})^m=(\frac{c}{a})^n-(\frac{b}{a})^n$
$\implies\ \boxed{\boxed{ m=n}}$

Comment: The last implication is not obvious to me.

Comment: How does that imply $m+n?.$

Comment: It's easier to show $c>a,b$ and thus $(a/c)^n+(b/c)^n$ is decreasing as $n$ is increasing. So it is not just true for positive integers $m,n,$ but positive real numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews after getting $(a/c)^n+(b/c)^n$ how did you proceed? Can you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: The function $f(x)=a^x+b^x-c^x$ has interesting properties for suitables $a,b,c$; in particular it just have one zero. For FLT (Wiles and Company) the only $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ must be necessarily irrational (algebraic or trascendental) when $x\not \in\{1,2\}$.